# SVN Working Copy to Different Branch Merge Without Commit to Working Copy Branch

Tags: svn, merge, working-copy

If a working copy (local copy) was created from a branch, lets call it A.  Coding was done in branch A, but branch A was "Closed" to commits, and branch b was opened.  How do I merge my working copy changes into Branch B and commit to branch B, without commiting my changes to branch A first.

Trunk -> branch A.

```
   I checked out branch A and made changes.
   Branch A was closed to commits.
```

New Branch created from branch A.
branch A -> branch B.

```
   I would like to commit my working copy changes (currently pointing at Branch A into branch B without commiting to Branch A)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Make backup of your working copy.
2. `svn switch` to branch `B`
3. review changes (base revision might differ, and svn does blind, dumb textual merges only), resolve conflicts, if any
4. commit

Doing things like this with a working copy with uncommitted changes is perilous. If anything goes wrong or if there are too many conflicting changes, rollback to your backed up version, create a temporary branch from your working copy's base revision of `A`, switch to that, and commit your changes, so they are somewhere safe. Then merge that branch into `B` whichever way you want and delete it afterwards.

Remember the svn mantra: ***Commit early, commit often***. If I have uncommitted changes lying around for more than one workday, I get nervous. Usually, I create a feature branch for any development lasting longer than a few hours. and regularly commit to that. When I'm done I merge it into wherever it came from and delete it afterwards.

Comment: This worked.  I did not need the backup, but it was good to have as you don't want to loose several days worth of work.

I like the svn mantra!

Answer (score 2):

To be very careful, I'd commit my changes to a private branch (let's call it `C`), then merge the `C` branch to the new open-for-commits branch `B`.

1. `cd` to working directory with changes you want to commit
2. `svn copy . C`
3. `cd ..` to your workspace folder with checkouts
4. `svn co B`
5. `cd` into B directory
6. `svn merge` the revision from step 2.
7. Review changes.
8. Commit!

Comment: Any documentation on what is a "private branch"?